# Laravel combination query of two tables

Tags: sql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I have the following tables:
[image]

What I want is to get the **product_types_values ptv** where their **ptv.type_id** == **1** and not exist any **variant v** where their **v.id_type** == **1** and its **v.value == ptv.value**

In SQL it will be like:

```
SELECT *
FROM products_types_values ptv
WEHRE ptv.type_id = 1 and ptv.value not in (SELECT v.value
                                            FROM variants v
                                            WEHRE v.type_id = 1)
```

For example, in the tables of the image, the result I want to get is the **products_types_values 8, 9, 10, 11, 12** and **13.**

In the controller I get some variants and product_types_values, and store them on $variants and $products_types_values. Maybe the solution is to work with these variables or to make another query.

My code is:

```
$variants = Variant::where('id_product', $id)->orderBy('id', 'Asc')->paginate(10);
$products_types_values = ProductTypeValue::where('type_id', $product->type_id)->orderBy('value', 'Asc')->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
ProductTypeValue::where('type_id', $product->type_id)
                ->whereNotIn('value', function ($query) use ($product) {
                    $query->select('v.value')
                          ->from('variants', 'v')
                          ->where('v.type_id', $product->type_id);
                })
                ->get();
```

Comment: Okey, and for example, if I have this `$variants = Variant::where('id_product', $id)->orderBy('id', 'Asc')->paginate(10);`, and I want to get the variant with the highest code, how can I achieve that without making another query? It's possible?

Comment: I don't think that's possible without at least making a subquery.

Comment: Maybe you could use a collection method. I think max() let's you pass a callback.

Comment: I guess you could also do something like `Variant::select('*')->selectSub(function ($sub) { $sub->selectRaw('max(code)')->from('variant'); }, 'max')->...`